# Catalan numbers in MIPS assembly

Tags: python, recursion, mips, catalan

Catalan numbers are recursively defined by the following equation.

[image]

This is the test case:

```
Program input:
0 1 2 3 6 9 
Expected output:
1 1 2 5 132 4862 
Obtained output:
1 1 2 4 32 256
```

So my output is wrong when n = 3, the output should be 5 and mine is 4, and so on.
here are my code:

```
catalan_recur:
addi $sp,$sp,-12
sw $ra,0($sp)
sw $s0,4($sp)
sw $a0,8($sp)
addi $t0,$0,1

bgt $a0,$t0,catalan_recur_else     #a0>1 ?
li $v0, 1
lw $s0, 4($sp)
lw $ra, 0($sp)
addiu $sp, $sp, 12
jr $ra

catalan_recur_else:
  li $t1,0         #res=0
  li $t2,0         #i=0
catalan_recur_loop:  
  bge $t2, $a0, end_loop  # if i >= n, exit loop
   # res += catalan_recur(i)*catalan_recur(n-i-1)
  move $a0, $t2              
  jal catalan_recur          # call catalan_recur(i)        
  add $s0,$0,$v0             # get return value and store in $s0
  lw $a0,8($sp)
  addi $t2,$t2,1             # i++
  sub $a0,$a0,$t2            # calculate n-i-1
  jal catalan_recur          # call catalan_recur(n-i-1)
  mult $s0,$s0,$v0           # catalan_recur(i) * catalan_recur(n-i-1)
  add $t1,$t1,$s0            # add to res
  lw $s0,4($sp)
  lw $a0,8($sp)
  j catalan_recur_loop  
        
end_loop:
  move $v0, $t1               # move res to $v0
  lw $a0,8($sp)
  lw $s0,4($sp)        
  lw $ra, 0($sp)
  addiu $sp, $sp, 12
jr $ra
```

pseudocode:

```
def catalan_recur(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1;
    else:
        res = 0
        for i in range(n):  # i = 0 ~ (n-1)
            res += catalan_recur(i) * catalan_recur(n-i-1)
         return res;

>> a0: the argument for the given positive integer input, n
```

I know I got wrong in the catalan_recur_loop, and the addition must miss some numbers, but I can't figure out how to fix the errors.

Answer (score 0):

The registers `$t1` and `$t2` are *caller-save*, so you have to save their values (on the stack) before calling functions inside functions not to lose the values.

Saving may be done like this:

```
  sw $t1,12($sp) # save $t1
  sw $t2,16($sp) # save $t2
  jal catalan_recur
  lw $t1,12($sp) # restore $t1
  lw $t2,16($sp) # restore $t2
```

Also don't forget to allocate the space to save on the stack (add/subtract `20` instead of `12` from the stack pointer)

Answer (score 0):

That function is saving and restoring `s0` for the benefit of the caller, `ra` for the benefit itself - so it knows where to return to, but saving `a0` and restoring it isn't benefitting anyone.  Like `ra`, `a0` belongs to the called function, the caller has no expectations on them, unlike with `s` registers.

You have correctly determined that an `s` register can be used to preserve a return value from one call that is needed after another call, however,
`n` initially in `a0`, `i`, and `res`, each also merit their own `s` registers.

For `n`, initially in a0, copy it to an `s` register in prologue, of course, after preseving the original value in that `s` register.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good but you should add mflo $s0 below mult $s0, $v0, since the result is returning not returning the lower 32 bits.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the result from the recursive did not pass back becuase of the $t register. I expanded the stack, and saved the result into the stack, and load it back and get the final value.

```
catalan_recur:
    addi $sp, $sp, -20   # Allocate space on stack for 5 items: $ra, $s0, $s1, $a0, and loop counter
    sw $ra, 0($sp)       # Save return address
    sw $s0, 4($sp)       # Save $s0 (we will use it for temporary storage)
    sw $s1, 8($sp)       # Save $s1 (used for accumulating result)
    sw $a0, 12($sp)      # Save original argument $a0 (n)
    sw $t2, 16($sp)      # Save $t2 if used before calling this function

    li $t0, 1            # Load immediate 1 into $t0 for comparison
    li $s1, 0            # Initialize accumulator for result in $s1

    ble $a0, $t0, return_one # If n <= 1, return 1 as Catalan number

    # Initialize loop counter, $t2 = 0
    li $t2, 0

loop_start:
    blt $t2, $a0, recursive_part # If $t2 < n, continue recursion
    j end_loop                   # Else, end loop

recursive_part:
    move $a0, $t2                # Prepare first argument for recursive call
    jal catalan_recur            # Recursive call catalan_recur(i)
    move $s0, $v0                # Store the result of catalan_recur(i) in $s0

    lw $a0, 12($sp)              # Restore $a0 (n) for calculation of n-i-1
    sub $a1, $a0, $t2            # n - i
    addi $a1, $a1, -1            # n - i - 1
    move $a0, $a1                # Prepare second argument for recursive call
    jal catalan_recur            # Recursive call catalan_recur(n-i-1)

    mul $s0, $s0, $v0            # Multiply results: catalan_recur(i) * catalan_recur(n-i-1)
    add $s1, $s1, $s0            # Accumulate in $s1

    lw $a0, 12($sp)              # Restore $a0 for next iteration
    addi $t2, $t2, 1             # Increment loop counter
    j loop_start                 # Jump back to start of loop

end_loop:
    move $v0, $s1                # Move accumulated result to $v0
    j cleanup                    # Jump to cleanup

return_one:
    li $v0, 1                    # Set return value to 1 for base case

cleanup:
    lw $ra, 0($sp)               # Restore $ra
    lw $s0, 4($sp)               # Restore $s0
    lw $s1, 8($sp)               # Restore $s1
    lw $a0, 12($sp)              # Restore $a0
    lw $t2, 16($sp)              # Restore $t2
    addi $sp, $sp, 20            # Deallocate stack space
    jr $ra                       # Return
```